# Why apps built with Angular2 are so heavy?

Tags: angular

Recently we planned to revamp our existing web-app which is built in `JMVC`. And we decided to go with Angular-2.

And to test what will be the load size, I did the following:

```
ng new test123
cd test123
ng build -prod
```

And deployed `dist` folder content on apache and it showed `1.0MB transferred`.

My entire JMVC application, with all the business logic is hardly 1.2MB when loaded in browser.

What can I do to decrease the size of Angular-2 app after deployment?

[image]

Comment: The Angular team is working on reducing the download size now.

Comment: Per [this](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/the-best-news-from-angulars-ng-conf-2016#angular-2-is-lean-and-fast) I thought they have already worked on it.

Comment: They are *still* working on it. ☺

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, the ng2 team are working on reducing the size of framework nearing its release.

Prior to this, following typical http conventions for minimising JS size is obviously the main thing, but I've also found that Webpacks optimisations heavily reduce the size of the generated JS substantially.

[image]

Thats 313KB for the entire angular2 code base as well as my entire app which includes inline HTML and Styling (I'm not sure what the result would be for a Hello World example though).

The webpack plugins you can use are

```
webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true)
webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Ian Belcher, This was helpful. Do you think at least for now I should not use angular-cli (as it uses systemJs) and move to webpack and install other dependencies like jasmin etc, on my own?

Comment: As with any project, I guess it depends on weighing up all the different variables and choosing what is right for your situation. Webpack has backing in the react community and while it appears that the core ng2 team back systemjs, the ng2 universal team appear to favour webpack. I'm not a massive fan of webpacks build pipeline and hence using gulp for most of our build tasks and webpack only for the concatenation of all assets. Unfortunately I can't comment of the cli tool either as I haven't used it. At this early stage of ng2, I think the right thing is choosing what feels right to you.

Comment: I'm quite sure that ng-cli uses webpack to bundle. not systemjs.